# CSS grid with 2 rows and infinite columns

Tags: css-grid

I want to create a grid which will contain action buttons. The final layout should be something like this:

```
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
    | 4 | 2 |
```

I'm discovering this but, let apart the fact that it starts from the right, I thought that the code should be as simple as this:

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 30px 30px;
grid-auto-columns: 30px;
```

So we say we have 2 rows of 30px height, and that the auto-added colums will be 30px width. But actually that doesn't render as expected at all:

https://codepen.io/Flaburgan/pen/NWXggyd

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally found how to control that, the property I was looking for is   `grid-auto-flow: column dense;`